# Getting a value for x depending on y

Tags: javascript, html, function, var

I'm trying to set x to a certain value depending on what the user enters y as. 
The user is able to enter a y value but my function is not printing x.
Anyone got any ideas? I haven't been able to find anything.

```js
var y = 12;
var x = paymentfrequency()

function paymentfrequency() {
  if (y = year) {
    x = 1;
  }
  if (y = quarter) {
    x = 4;
  }
  if (y = month) {
    x = 12;
  }
  if (y = fortnight) {
    x = 26;
  }
  if (y = week) {
    x = 52;
  }
  return x = 0
}

document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;
```

```html
<b>The text is: </b><span id="output"> </span>
```

Comment: = sets a value....

Comment: Have you defined `year`, `quarter`, `month`, `fortnight` and `week` anywhere else?

Comment: why are you returning `x=0`?

Comment: @Booligoosh Yes,  year, quarter, month, fortnight and week are defined and y does display a result of one of those 5 options

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show *all* of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming year, quarter, month, fortnight and week have been defined):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<b>The text is: </b><span id="output"> </span>

<script>

 var y = 12;
  var x = paymentfrequency()

  function paymentfrequency() {
    var out;
    if (y == year) { out = 1;
    } if (y == quarter) {out = 4;
    } if (y == month) {out = 12;
    } if (y == fortnight) {out = 26;
    } if (y == week) {out = 52;
    } return(out);
  }

document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you should be using `===` instead of `=` in the `if` statements. `===` tests for equality and returns `true` or `false`; `=` is the assignment operator, meaning that `y` is getting set to `year` in the first `if` statement.

Similarly, the function is returning `x = 0`, which sets `x` to `0` regardless of whatever code you ran before it. Either return `x` inside each `if` statement, so that the final `return` isn't always reached, or set `x` equal to `0` at the beginning, then return it no matter what at the end. (This is assuming you want `x` to be set to `0` if none of the other `if` statements are true.)

I recommend fixing these two errors, and if your output still isn't displaying properly, creating a new question. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues `=` sets a value `==` compares a value, loosely and `===` compares a value strictly (the types have to be the same). There are pleanty of articles out there on the difference between `==` and `===`.

Next you are always returning `x=0` which makes no sense really.

Moving on... each of your `if` statements is evaluated. You would be better of with `if.elseif..else` statements or even better [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Finally you are better off not trying to work with a variable outside your function, better to pass it in as a parameter.

So putting it all you get

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<b>The text is: </b><span id="output"> </span>

<script>

 var y = 12;
  var x = paymentfrequency(y)

  function paymentfrequency(input) {
    var out;
    //Assuming year, month, quater etc are global variables set else where
    switch(input) 
    {
       case year:
          out = 1;
          break;
       case quarter:
          out = 4;
          break;
       case month:
          out = 12;
          break;
       case  fortnight:
          out = 26;
          break;
       case week:
          out = 52;
          break;
       default:
          out = 0;
          break;
    } 

    return(out);
  }

document.getElementById("output").innerText = x;

</script>
</body>
</html>
```